# Einstein's remark on the invariant nature of mass

Tags: special-relativity, mass

Since mass is a Lorentz invariant, it can never change to preserve the vectorial nature of the four-momentum and the other four vectors. Thus the idea that mass changes as speed increases is highly discouraged. However, Einstein in *The Meaning of Relativity* said that

> The mass of a body is not a constant, it varies with changes in its
> energy.

Why is that?

Comment: Einstein said it each way at different times, but his later comments generally referred to invariant mass. The "Meaning of Relativity" was 1922.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin Einstein actually revised it quite a few times. The edition that I have is from 1954.

Comment: I think later editions were reprints of the original edition.  The original edition was a summary of lectures that Einstein had given at Princeton.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin In the preface of 1954 Einstein states that he completely revised the fourth lecture's notes, so I think he must have read the other lectures too.

Comment: I hadn't read the 1954 edition.  So I guess he still said that in 1954.

Comment: I saw this on the internet: Interestingly, whenever the subject of “relativistic mass” comes up in conversation today, someone mentions a letter that Einstein evidently wrote to Barnett on June 19, 1948 after seeing Barnett’s articles. In this letter  Einstein wrote (in German)
"…it is not proper to speak of the mass M = m(1 – v2/c2)–1/2 of a moving body, because no clear definition can be given for M. It is better to restrict oneself to the ‘rest mass’, m. Besides, one may of course use the expressions for momentum and energy when referring to the inertial behavior of rapidly moving bodies."

Answer (score 1):

*Rest* mass is Lorentz invariant.

*Relativistic* mass is the same thing as energy.

Einstein was referring to relativistic mass. That used to be what we called "mass". It is, however, fashionable to call rest mass "mass" nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

> Since mass is a Lorentz invariant, it can never change

Yes, the rest mass is invariant. Nowadays, we usually just say "mass" instead of "rest mass." So what you wrote above is correct.

For example, when I write the symbol $m$ in the below formula, it stands for rest mass:
$$
E^2 = m^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2\;.
$$

Sometimes people use the symbol $m_0$ for rest mass, in which they would write:
$$
E^2 = m_0^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2\;.
$$

> However, Einstein in *The Meaning of Relativity* said that
>
> > The mass of a body is not a constant, it varies with changes in its
> > energy.
>
> Why is that?

When Einstein used the word "mass" he didn't mean "rest mass," he presumably meant the "relativistic mass," which is the rest mass multiplied by $\gamma\equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$.

For example, if I let $m$ denote the rest mass (which is invariant) we have:
$$
E = mc^2 \gamma\;,
$$
where the "relativistic mass" is $m\gamma$.

For example, if I let $m_0$ denote the rest mass (which is invariant) we have:
$$
E = m_0c^2 \gamma\;.
$$
where the "relativistic mass" is $m_0\gamma$.